# Вывод массива из функции

Tags: php

Добрый день столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой.
Есть класс в котором функция возвращает результат массив. Далее необходимо вывести два эллемента массива в разных местах. подскажите как это сделать??

```
class Ccontent extends Mcontent
    {

        function ccont($pages)
        {
            $res = $this->content($pages);
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

            //print_r($myrow);
            return $arr = array('title' => $myrow["title"], 'content' => $myrow["text"]);

        }
    }
$ccontent = new Ccontent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не пойму в чем сложность или вы что-то не досказали.

```
$ccontent = new Ccontent;
$res_arr = $ccontent->ccont($page_id);
// выводим в одном месте
echo $res_arr['title'];
// выводим где-нибудь еще
echo $res_arr['content'];
```

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался ))

Answer (score 0):

Все решение нашел. В классе объявляем переменную $arr затем пишем следующие

```
$ccontent->ccont($page);
    echo $ccontent->arr["content"];
```

Всего делов.